# Video Image as Plane renders differently on render farm

Tags: rendering, video

As seen in the images below, when my scene renders by command line on my render farm, the Image as Plane (a .mov video of a flame with Alpha transparency) renders looking red. It looks fine when rendered on my local machine as shown. I have packed the file before sending to the render farm. Both my workstation and the render farm are using 3.3.1, using cycles, and rendering using CPU. There is a point light right where the flame from the video is located. I tried changing alpha settings from Straight to Premultiplied, but that was not it. Any idea where I am going wrong?

[image: correct render]

[image: problem render]

Comment: As far as I know, video files cannot be packed. You should use a Relative Path instead, and copy the video file to your renderfarm.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not aware of video's not being packed.

Comment: Here's what I learned for if you want to sent your blendfile with a video out from your workstation for rendering or sharing: Relative paths are the default when setting up images (and videos in my case) in the shader editor. To make things easy, when setting up a video in your scene, first put the video in the same directory as your blendfile, then choose it in the shader editor. This way, its relative path is simply the directory the blendfile is in. Then when you share the blendfile or send it to the renderfarm, you can just drop the video in the same directory as @thibsert pointed out.